# Linq Lambda expression for scalar value (max)

Tags: linq

Can anyone convert the following SQL query into a lambda expression?

```
select MAX(orderid) from tblCustomers where parentid = 1002
```

Thanks

Comment: What language should this be?

Comment: Well yes, we could do that - but it would be nice to see what you'd already tried first, and where you've become unstuck, so that we don't just feel like a code-writing service...

Comment: LINQ to what? SQL, Entities? How is your context set? How are your entities defined?

Answer (score 6):

In C#

```
var maxOrderId = db.tblCustomers
    .Where(c => c.parentid == 1002)
    .Max(c => c.orderid);
```